# Incorrect output from InverseFourierTransform

Tags: functions, bugs, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and fixed in 9.0.1 or earlier**

---

I am trying to compute the inverse Fourier transform of this expression

```
fhat[w_] = (Exp[-2*I*w] + Exp[2*I*w])
```

using

```
f[x_] = InverseFourierTransform[fhat[w], w, x, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

Here, Mathematica correctly returns

```
DiracDelta[-2 + x] + DiracDelta[2 + x]
```

However, when (when using Mathematica 8) I try to compute this

```
fhat[w_] = 5*(Exp[-2*I*w] + Exp[2*I*w])
```

I get `0` as the inverse Fourier Transform, which is clearly incorrect.  The result should be `5*(DiracDelta[-2 + x] + DiracDelta[2 + x])`.

Can anyone explain to me this behavior? Do you know a way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: I guess you are in v8? I can reproduce this in this version.  v9 and v10 give the correct result.

Comment: You are right, I am in v8. So I will have to update...
Is this a known bug of v8?

Comment: I think it's not, at least I can't find an exact duplicate. Here's just a possible related one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34027/1871

Comment: This is clearly incorrect behaviour.